# Apollo-Client graphql subscriptions from cache similar field policy read for query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Is it possible with apollo-client to provide first results for a subscription from cache similar to the cache-and-network fetchPolicy of a watchQuery?

For queries [client side resolvers are possible with the read function with field policies.](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions) I'm looking for similar for subscriptions.

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          book(_, { args, toReference }) {
            return toReference({
              __typename: 'Book',
              id: args.id,
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I tried the following, but it seems this hook is not called for subscription or am I missing something?

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Subscriptions: { // Is it Subscription or Subscriptions?
        fields: {
          books(_, { args, toReference }) {
            console.log("subscription read not called?", args);
            return args.ids.map(
              id => toReference({
                __typename: 'Book',
                id: id,
              })
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Leaving also the following questions open to me:

- How to resolve multiple results from cache and how to return them?
- Just return array of toReference or use a pub/sub rx stream?

Thx community, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I’d also be interested in how to return multiple results!

Comment: Hi Manuel, did you ever managed to figure this out?

Comment: @Stathis, nothing I would call the perfect solution. Right now using a query/watchQuery on cache only and a concurrent subscripeToMore over network

Comment: Thanks @Manuel, this seems really tricky to implement. Thanks for the reply.